# how can i increase mouse pointer area in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I make the game "bugs killer" with mouse pointer, and I use the bottle image on a cursor that spray on bugs, 
but the problem is that spray not kill the bugs, when bottle goes on bugs that kill with onclick.
so can any one tell me how can i solve this problem? 
how can I increase mouse pointer area in javascript ????

This is the code of spray animation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

// for Spray Animation

function clickEffect(e){

    var d=document.createElement("div");
    d.className="clickEffect";
    d.style.top=e.clientY+"px";d.style.left=e.clientX+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    d.addEventListener('animationend',function(){d.parentElement.removeChild(a);}.bind(this));}

    document.addEventListener('click',clickEffect);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "increase" the mouse pointer.
What you need to do is implement basic collision detection.
We can't tell you how to do it because there are whole books about this, but here are the steps i'd go through if i wanted a super-simple collision detection.

1) Register a click event and store the mouse position

2) Extend the mouse coordinates to cover a larger surface (for example leftLimit = mouseposition x - 10)

3) Loop through all your bugs or whatever you need to be able to click on. Calculate the space and position they occupy on your screen. If the bug's limit are within the range of the mouse click, destroy it

Comment: can you please tell me how i do it ?, because its take time , and i dont have more time to spend it, can you please help me in this matter? , i shall be very thankful to you

Comment: Sorry, writing a complete tutorial covering your case would take about an hour and it really isn't the purpose of stackoverflow. There are tons of tutorials out there that will help you get a grip on things.
http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection

Comment: i registered the click event and store the mouse position, now tell me how to extend the mouse co-ordinates ? give me some bunch of code to set this . please

Comment: You don't actually "extend the mouse". Let's assume, that you click at coordinates x:50, y:30. What you do is that you store 50 - 10, 50 + 10, 30 - 10 and 30 + 10.

Now you have to check every item for collision by checking their coordinates and width / height. You can calculate if they overlap the area you want to check and delete them if that's the case.

Comment: i stored the coordinates of mouse : function printMousePos(event) {
 var Mouseposition =
  "X: " + (event.clientX-10)  +
  " - Y: " + (event.clientY+10);
  document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = Mouseposition;
}
document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);